# How to mock a `FutureProvider.autodispose`?

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider the following provider:

```dart
final provider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<Metadata>(
  (ref) async {
    final response = await ref.read(service).run();
    return response;
  },
  dependencies: [service],
  name: 'provider',
);
```

I would like to mock this provider to be able to manipulate its state (`AsyncData`, `AsyncError`, etc..). Currently I have the following code:

```dart
abstract class _Create<T> {
  FutureOr<T> call(AutoDisposeFutureProviderRef<T> ref);
}

class _ProviderCreate extends Mock implements _Create<Metadata> {}

test('test', () async {
      final mockFunction = _ProviderCreate();
      final container = ProviderContainer(
        overrides: [
          provider.overrideWith(mockFunction),
        ],
      );
      final listener = ListenerMock<HomeScreenMetadata>();
      // homePageProvider is a second provider that watch `provider`
      container.listen<HomePageMetadata>(homePageProvider, listener, fireImmediately: true);

      when(() => mockFunction.call(any())).thenAnswer((_) async {
        // This mock is never called
        print("called");
        ...
      });

      await container.pump();
      
      const homePageUnloaded = HomePageMetadata(loaded: false);
      const homePageLoaded = HomeScreenMetadata(loaded: true);

      verifyInOrder(
        [
          () => listener(null, homePageUnloaded),
          () => listener(homePageUnloaded, homePageLoaded),
        ],
      );

      verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
    });
```

But the mock of `mockFunction` is never called for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the container on each tests instead of using a mock a function that could be overwritten on each test. Working code:

```dart
test('test', () async {
      final listener = ListenerMock<HomePageMetadata>();
      container.listen<HomePageMetadata>(homeScreenProvider, listener, fireImmediately: true);

      container.updateOverrides([
        provider.overrideWith((_) async => // TODO: Return the expected value here),
      ]);

      await container.pump();

      const homePageUnloaded = HomePageMetadata(loaded: false);
      const homePageLoaded = HomeScreenMetadata(loaded: true);

      verifyInOrder(
        [
          () => listener(null, homePageUnloaded),
          () => listener(homePageUnloaded, homePageLoaded),
        ],
      );

      verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
    });
```